# @font-face not working on tumblr

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've decided to make my own tumblr theme and I have a little problem. I'm trying to add a personal font and I used theme assets, so the font is uploaded [here](http://static.tumblr.com/ql72inh/AyIomnie6/moon_light.ttf).
The css code is:

```
@font-face {
font-family: moon;
src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ql72inh/AyIomnie6/moon_light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

If you acces the blog [here](http://derovada.tumblr.com) you will see that the menu on the right doesn't have the font that I want. I used `font-family:moon;` so I really don't understand why doesn't it work

Comment: "Access to Font at 'https://secure.static.tumblr.com/ql72inh/AyIomnie6/moon_light.ttf' from origin 'https://derovada.tumblr.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://derovada.tumblr.com' is therefore not allowed access." This is the error in the console. [This might help.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: @Jmrburgard I just thought I should check the console haha, so what does that actually mean, do you have any idea? Or how could I fix it

Comment: Check the link I put in. I'm not sure the exact issue, put it has to do with permissions and stuff.